# some parts of HTML form not sent on POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post

I have a strange issue with my form data being POST via AJAX. Some parts of the form are not being sent. Specifically, the date and time parts. Here's my form:

```
<script src="/js/x.js" ></script>

<div class="right">
  <form id="xForm" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
    <input id="xname" name="xname" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address" />
    <br/>
    <input id="fromdate" name="fromdate" type="date" />
    <input id="fromtime" name="fromtime" type="time" />
    <br/>
    <input id="todate" name="todate" type="date" />
    <input id="totime" name="totime" type="time" />
    <br/>
    <input id="description" name="description" type="text" />
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="phone" />
    <input id="friend1" name="friend1" type="hidden" />
    <input id="friend2" name="friend2" type="hidden" />    
    <button class="xCreateButton" type="submit">create!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I send it using my POST ajax call (the code in `/js/X.js`):

```
$("#xForm").submit(function(evt)
{
   evt.preventDefault();

   alert ("date = " + document.getElementById("fromdate").value);
   $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/xSubmission",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response)
            {
                alert (response);
          $("#eventAjaxContent").text = "Success! Added!";
              $("#eventAjaxContent").fadeOut (300);          
            }
      });
```

it sends the form data except the `fromdate/time` and `todate/time` (I check this in my server logs for Spring MVC controller `/xSubmission` and my console debugger on Chrome). BTW, just before the ajax POST, I see the alert for the date set correctly.

What is so wrong about fromdate/time and todate/time in my code? As you can see, the input elements all have an `id` and a `name` so that is not an issue. Anythinh in the syntax I should be aware of?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unbelievable! I think you are right, @showdev, I was using jQuery 1.3. I moved to 1.10 and the problem went away. What a weird, and untrackable problem (i.e., if you are not in the know!).

Answer (score 1):

Move to a later version of jQuery. I was using 1.3. Moving to jQuery 1.10 fixed the problem.